# PrismaJS Rating Avg System

Tags: postgresql, prisma, next.js13

I use PrismaJS, nextjs and Postgresql.

I want to filter in the Listing model according to the ** rating average ** value from SearchParams. Since the rating value is in the comment model, I cannot get the rating avg value in the Listing model. For this reason, I cannot do the filtering process.

```
const fetchListing= async (searchParams: SearchParams) => {
  let where: any = {};
  const rating = searchParams.rating ?? Number(searchParams.rating);
  const page = searchParams.page ? Number(searchParams.page) : 1;
  const limit = 4;
  const offset = (page - 1) * limit;

  const count = await prisma.listing.count({ where });
  const totalPages = Math.ceil(count / limit);

  const listing = await prisma.listing.findMany({
    where,
    select: {
      id: true,
      title: true,
      slug: true,
      seotitle: true,
      geoAddress: true,
      content: true,
      image: true,
      seoexcerpt: true,
      comments: true,
      _count: {
        select: {
          comments: true,
        },
      },
    },
    skip: offset,
    take: limit,
  });

  return { listing  count, totalPages };
```

**PRISMA SCHEMA**

```
model Listing {
  id          String      @id @default(cuid()) @map("id")
  slug        String      @unique
  seotitle    String?
  seoexcerpt  String?
  image       String?
  title       String
  content     String
  published   PostPublish @default(DRAFT)
  author      User        @relation(fields: [authorId], references: [id])
  authorId    String
  createdAt   DateTime    @default(now())
  updatedAt   DateTime    @updatedAt
  geoAddress  String?
  coordinates String[]
  country     Country     @relation("CountryToListing", fields: [countryId], references: [id])
  countryId   Int
  comments    Comment[]
  favoritedBy Favorite[]
}

model Comment {
  id                String         @id @default(cuid()) @map("id")
  user              User           @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  userId            String
  comment           String
  commentTitle      String
  post              Listing        @relation(fields: [postId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
  postId            String
  status            CommentPublish @default(DRAFT)
  createdAt         DateTime       @default(now())
  pros              String?
  cons              String?
  accommodationDate DateTime?
  rating            Int
  userFeedback      String[]
}
```